# How to develop without a production org?

Tags: licenses, change-set, import

We'd like to begin work on a Salesforce custom app, but do not yet have access to a production org and user licenses. We believe we'll have the licenses within 30 days, but are unsure.

In the meantime, one possibility we were considering was beginning development in a Salesforce training org and migrating the custom application, custom objects, workflows, and validation rules  over to the production org once we have the licenses. How feasible is this approach? Are there alternatives? We do worry that the training environment will expire before we receive the licenses, and we are concerned about the limitations that the Developer Edition training org has compared to the Enterprise Edition production org.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy components between environments that are independent of each other (i.e. not Production-Sandbox envs) you will need to use the Force.com migration tool.

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) is a guide on that.

It would also be advisable to set up some tools to automate this deployment process, Jenkins is a popular option with optional integration with a source control system such as GitHub.

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html) is a guide on setting up Jenkins as a CI server.